# Check unused tables in Snowflake views

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

in Snowflake I am trying to have the list of all the tables of my schema that are not used in any views. I have a python script where I connect to Snowflake, I take the list of my tables and my views that are in my schema and I want to have the list of all the tables that are in my tables list but not used for views.

At first I tried with the following query:

```
`SELECT REFERENCED_SCHEMA_NAME, REFERENCED_OBJECT_NAME, REFERENCED_OBJECT_TYPE FROM TABLE(GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES(DATABASE_NAME => 'ANALYTICS', SCHEMA_NAME => '{schema}', OBJECT_NAME => '{view}'))`
```

The problem is that for some views I have the following error: Object Object is a FUNCTION. Function is not supported as input or output of this function.

Comment: Hi - if you look in the Snowflake QUERY_HISTORY can you see the actual statement that is generating this error? If so, can you update your question with the statement? I'm wondering if {schema} and/or {view} are being replaced with invalid values

Comment: Do you have functions with the same names as your views?

Comment: I think some conflict with view / function name, My recommendation is capture the all the object which throwing error by adding exception and investigate the issues with object and implement the fix.